# Holding a Strong ref to local object that uses closure [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, memory, closures, strong-parameters

I have a question regarding holding a Strong ref to local object that uses closure.
I have the following code, which object B uses a method with closure of a local object of type A.
The method in object A, uses async action to perform some network task and then return the closure to object b.
Since object A is local in a method in B and since i'm using [weak self] in the the object A async task (to prevent retain cycle), the object gets released.

What should i change in the following code in order to ensure the local A object will get released only when the closure is done?

This is part of the important code:

```
class A {
    var restAPI: RestAPI?

    func fetchNews(completion: (_ json: [String:Any])->()) {
        // .....
        self.restAPI.fetch(url: url, results: { [weak self] (json) in // 
            completion(json)
        })
        // .....
    }
}

class B {
    // .... 
    // ... call to updateNews()

    func updateNews() {
        let aFetcher: A() 
        aFetcher.fetchNews(completion : { 
            // <<<< // aFetcher gets released and closue never called
            // parse...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, there's no good solution for this problem. Main problems are thread-safety. You are better off defining and initialising the variable `restAPI` "outside" in the class A instance that MUST out-live the class B instance. You also need to destroy it on the same thread where you created it. This is best done in instance of class A again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare *aFetcher* as a let in the scope of func updateNews()
When the scope of *updateNews(*) reaches its end aFetcher will be released.
Your have *[weak self]* in your internal fetch function.
On this stage aFetcher will be released because updateNews() finish its executing and there are no strong references to this object.

You just need to add variable *aFetcher* to class B to ensure you have strong reference to *aFetcher*.

```
class B {

    // MARK: - Vars
    private let aFetcher = A()

    // MARK: - Public
    func updateNews() {
        aFetcher.fetchNews(completion : {
            // parse...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a strong reference on the top level of the class.

However not to keep the reference permanently and to retain and release it reliably add a optional stored property in `class B` and set it to `nil` in the completion closure:

```
class B {

    var fetcher : A?

    // MARK: - Public
    func updateNews() {
        fetcher = A()
        fetcher!.fetchNews(completion : { [unowned self] in
            // parse...

            self.fetcher = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, but what if I want the variable to be local and not a class property ? What shall I do then?

Comment: Actually it's not a *class* property it's an *instance* property. Nevertheless you need a strong reference – which cannot be local – to the instance of class A

Comment: IMHO it's not a good pattern. It also bears a subtle issue: if the completion handler keeps the last strong ref to the object, it will be destructed on this thread when the completion handler executes. Since the thread where it has been created   (where `updateNews()` will be called) may be another one, this yields a data race. In order to make it work, you need "Thread confinement" (another bad pattern), but then you don't need the var fetcher in class B anyway.